# Cloudinary python uploader not working

Tags: python, cloudinary

```
import cloudinary
cloudinary.uploader.upload("my_picture.jpg")
```

Gives error

> AttributeError: module 'cloudinary' has no attribute 'uploader'

Comment: Please copy the **full** traceback, not just the last line.

Comment: FWIW, I hit the same error, and that's full traceback.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It usually happens when running it from a script called Cloudinary. Try to rename cloudinary.py to something else.. Also, delete cloudinary.pyc if exists.

Answer (score 30):

I solved this by also adding this import statement:

```
import cloudinary.uploader
```